# R: count number of observations before and after date

Tags: r, filter, count

I have a data frame with these columns: one with dates (YYYY-MM-DD),  one with years (YYYY in numeric form), one with ids of individuals and others with characteristics.

I want to filter out individuals so that only those with at least 10 observations before and 5 after a date (minimum sum total of 15) remain and the rest filtered out. Filtering by either date or year is fine.

Can you think of any way to do this that doesnt include lots of new dataframes with which I compare the original one - to speed up the process?

Comment: Can you please show a small reproducible example with expected output so that others can test

Comment: Write a function that works for one individual, and use `tapply` or `dplyr::filter` to apply it to all individuals at once.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar and was hoping to find some code to save time...

I didn't find an immediate equivalent so here's my solution using data.table:

Create a data table with similar structure:

```
ID_seq <- c(5,5,6,8,9,9,9)
dt <- setDT(data.frame(ID = sequence(ID_seq)))
setkey(dt, ID)
dt[, YR := 1:.N, by = .(ID)]
dt$event <- rep(0, nrow(dt))
dt$event[c(4,11,17,25,38,46)] <- 1 # strategically place events
```

then it's a matter of creating a column that meets the condition. I  set it so that there must be at least 3 years before and after the event. Building on that [post](http://Building%20on%20this%20post):

```
dt2 <- dt[, counter := seq_len(.N), by = list(ID, cumsum(event == 1L))][, cond := fifelse(sum(counter == 3) >  1, 1, 0), by = ID][cond == 1 ,]
```

For the poster's situation, it would just be a matter of changing the condition in the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Flags data frame with 194 obs and 30 variables]
Flags data frame with 194 obs and 30 variables

Filter `flags` data frame, using `select`, use `dplyr::filter` to get desired column and `str_detect` for string criteria:

```
   df <- select(flags, name) %>% filter(str_detect(flags$name, "^Al"))

print(df)

    name
1 Albania
2 Algeria
```