# In R: subset so that I only have observations at least 3 years prior to and after an event

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I had previously asked the following question: [In R: subset so that I only have the observations 3 years prior to and after an event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67255031/15388602)

How do I do the same but with a restriction of at least 3 years before or after the date instead of that it has to be exact 3 years before and after?

If I have data like this:

```
companyID   year   status
    1       2000     1
    1       2001     1
    1       2002     1
    1       2003     1
    1       2004     0
    1       2005     2
    1       2006     2
    1       2007     2
    2       2012     1
    2       2013     0
    2       2014     2
    2       2015     2
    2       2016     2
    3       2008     1
    3       2009     1
    3       2010     1
    3       2011     1
    3       2012     1
    3       2013     0
    3       2014     2
    3       2015     2
    3       2016     2
    3       2017     2
```

I would therefore like my data to look something like this:

```
companyID   year   status
    1       2000     1
    1       2001     1
    1       2002     1
    1       2003     1
    1       2004     0
    1       2005     2
    1       2006     2
    1       2007     2
    3       2008     1
    3       2009     1
    3       2010     1
    3       2011     1
    3       2012     1
    3       2013     0
    3       2014     2
    3       2015     2
    3       2016     2
    3       2017     2
```

Thanks in advance for your guidance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a helper function you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

select_rows <- function(status) {
  inds <- match(0, status)
  inds >= 4 && length(status) >= (inds + 3)
  #inds >= 4 ensures there are atleast 3 years before the event
  #length(status) >= (inds + 3) ensures there are atleast 3 years after
}

df %>%
  arrange(companyID, year) %>%
  group_by(companyID) %>%
  filter(select_rows(status)) %>%
  ungroup

#   companyID  year status
#       <int> <int>  <int>
# 1         1  2000      1
# 2         1  2001      1
# 3         1  2002      1
# 4         1  2003      1
# 5         1  2004      0
# 6         1  2005      2
# 7         1  2006      2
# 8         1  2007      2
# 9         3  2008      1
#10         3  2009      1
#11         3  2010      1
#12         3  2011      1
#13         3  2012      1
#14         3  2013      0
#15         3  2014      2
#16         3  2015      2
#17         3  2016      2
#18         3  2017      2
```